# Increment number in filename for avoid overwriting wav file in a loop

Tags: python, wav, pydub

i'm a novice in python and i'm trying to loop in a directory with the goal of divide each wav files contained in the folder in many chunks.
I've successfully looped and divided the files but when i try to export the chunks in a new folder i can't figure it out how to change the chunk names created so that all are saved successfully (without overwriting).

```
import os
from pydub import AudioSegment

path = ""

os.chdir(path)

audio_files = os.listdir()

for file in audio_files:

    name, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
    if ext == ".wav":
        w = AudioSegment.from_wav(file)
        chunk_length_ms = 3000 
        chunks = make_chunks(w, chunk_length_ms) 
        for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
            chunk_name = "{0}.wav".format(name)
            print ("exporting", chunk_name)
            chunk.export('dir_path' + chunk_name, format="wav")
```

With this code only 100 chunks are saved successfully instead of 1100.
the wav files have this name structure: "genre.000x.wav", so for ex. 'Blues.00001.wav' should be chunked in : 'Blues.00001a.wav','Blues.00001b.wav',ecc.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a away of adding successive lowercase letters to each file name you export in your loop:

```
chunks = ['chunk1', 'chunk2', 'chunk3']
name = 'Blues.00001'

for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
    chunk_name = "{0}{1}.wav".format(name, chr(ord('a')+i))
    print ("exporting", chunk_name)
```

Result:

```
exporting Blues.00001a.wav
exporting Blues.00001b.wav
exporting Blues.00001c.wav
```